# Long first time to plot with Gadfly

Tags: performance, math, julia

I created simple plotting example with Julia

```
using Gadfly
draw(SVG("example.svg", 10cm, 10cm),
  plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10))
)
```

And ran it as `time julia example.jl` it took it `27` sec to finish. Is it normal behaviour? Is it possible to speed it up?

*Latest Julia 0.5.2 and Pkg.*

Comment: Yes, it's normal. It's only when you load the package though.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I guess almost any practical scripts have to load one package or another. Even this toy example requires it.

Comment: Yes. Julia is most useful for having an open session that you work with for extended periods of time - not for running a quick out-of-terminal script that opens and closes the session at once.
That said, it is mainly plotting that takes so long.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I'd say plotting is essential for math-related software.

Comment: I'd say so to. I do plotting all the time. But I usually work in the interactive REPL. It sounds like you have a habit of developing a script, then running that script from bash. That's fine, but it's not the recommended way of working with julia.

Comment: Despite it's name, Gadfly has never been the quickest for plotting. Have a look at GR. [Here](https://juliaplots.github.io/backends/)'s a summary of some strengths and weaknesses of various Julia plotting packages. Notice that Gadfly isn't mentioned...

Comment: Plots is not the fastest loader either, though it helps a lot to be on master (which has precompilation activated). But after the first plot, Plots (with e.g. GR) is practically instantaneous.

Comment: I've made a simple plot server example [here](https://gist.github.com/Ismael-VC/3b517d02a3e7e7a90d80) it is a way to workaround the issue that may work for your workflow.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert so take this with a pinch of salt, but you're `draw` and `SVG` functions are compiled the first time they're run, that's why the long running time.
If you call the function again, it takes a lot less time. You're paying a penalty to compile the function calls first, but all later executions are quite quick.

I amended you're script to measure the time spent in different calls:

```
@time using Gadfly
@time draw(SVG("example.svg", 10cm, 10cm),
  plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10))
)
@time draw(SVG("example2.svg", 10cm, 10cm),
  plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10))
)
```

Running this from the console with `julia example.jl` gives me the following:

```
$ julia example.jl
2.728577 seconds (3.32 M allocations: 141.186 MB, 10.29% gc time)
20.434172 seconds (27.48 M allocations: 1.109 GB, 1.95% gc time)
0.023084 seconds (32.59 k allocations: 1.444 MB)
```

Comment: Yea, but I do care about the first time too. If you have to wait 20-30 sec after every change in the script that makes quick development quite hard...

Comment: It means that it caters to different programming habits. As long as you keep your session open you'll not feel it.

Comment: That said, if you are developing a package yourself, you can use the module organization via Juno to avoid the reloading time. I don't know if this is what you'd like to do though?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard In my opinion being able to run a simple script is a basic requirement, if it's not there, I'm afraid I better try something else than try to fight it. I was shocked that fast Julia takes 30 sec and hoped that' it's some sort of mistake.

Comment: "Yea, but I do care about the first time too. If you have to wait 20-30 sec after every change in the script that makes quick development quite hard"
I don't know where you get that from. You need to recompile Gadfly each time you open Julia, not each time you change a script. There's a big difference. But if first-time-to-plot matters, don't use Gadfly. That's the wrong library for the job. Use PyPlot or GR instead. This has nothing to do with Julia and instead is a library issue.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin *I'm afraid I better try something else than try to fight it.* So you just wanted to **try** if Julia works like something you've already **learned**? I would like to suggest you to **learn** not to **try**. [Empty your cup of tea!](http://wiki.c2.com/?EmptyYourCup) :)

Comment: That long startup time mostly has to do with packages not being precompiled.  When packages are precompiled, then that first time to X goes down drastically. Some of the older packages haven't been updated to use precompilation yet, which I believe leads to Gadfly's slow load times. With precompilation, the very first time you have "using X" will be slow, but then will be cached and will be fast on all sessions, so you don't have to keep a session open.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to do the same example with `GR.jl` as suggested by @daycaster and got 3.3 seconds on one laptop with Windows 10 64 bits:

```
PS C:\Users\dell\plot_example> cat plot.jl
using GR
plot(rand(10), rand(10), size = (500, 500))
savefig("plot.svg")

PS C:\Users\dell\plot_example> Measure-Command {julia plot.jl}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 3
Milliseconds      : 382
Ticks             : 33822083
TotalDays         : 3.91459293981481E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000939502305555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.0563701383333333
TotalSeconds      : 3.3822083
TotalMilliseconds : 3382.2083
```

Version and CPU:

```
PS C:\Users\dell\plot_example> julia -q
julia> VERSION
v"0.5.1"

julia> Sys.cpu_info()[]
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz:
        speed         user       nice        sys       idle        irq ticks
     2304 MHz   18360406          0   10161406  218911218    2123421 ticks
```

Example plot:

[image]